# find by name the id of a multi level categorie

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, odoo

my main problem is how can i search by name the id of a given category, let me explain , so ,in my database i have a table called product_category where is stored a 5 level categories. let's take an example of it:

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 2 |
| 4 | D |  |
| 5 | A | 4 |
| 6 | B | 5 |
| 7 | C | 6 |

so from this table let's take these two categories :

- A/B/C
- D/A/B/C

in my table the categories name are redundant but don't have the same id, now let's say that i want to search the id of this category (A/B/C) , is it possible in my case ? knowing that there's two categories named C with different ids , the same with B an A.

i am using python and odoo , but i didn't find a way to solve this especially that in my data base there is redundant names.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @Serg the disired output is the id of this category A/B/C

Comment: @simeh: so that would be `3`? (= the ID of the `C` category)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive query that builds up the full path for each category, then filter on that full path in the final select:

```
with recursive tree as (
  select id, name, parent_id, name as full_path
  from category 
  where parent_id is null
  union all
  select c.id, c.name, c.parent_id, concat(p.full_path, '/', c.name) as full_path
  from category  c
    join tree p on p.id = c.parent_id
)
select id, name, parent_id
from tree
where full_path = 'A/B/C'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [complete_name](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/product/models/product.py#L27) field is a stored computed field, so it can be used in search domains.

***Example (odoo 15):***

```
self.env['product.category'].search([('complete_name', '=', 'A / B / C')])
```

***Example (odoo 8):***

```
self.env['product.category'].search([('name', '=', 'C'), ('parent_id.name', '=', 'B'), ('parent_id.parent_id.name', '=', 'A'), ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id', '=', False)])
```

Comment: Does this answer help you?

Comment: Thank you, i'm working on odoo 8 , i've tried this but it doesn't give the right id , instead it's giving me a big list of ids

Comment: Yes, it won't work for odoo 8. You can use dotted field names in the search domain.

Comment: Check my edit (example for odoo 8)